# Using the_widget Multiple Times

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to build a widget to includes another widgets.

I've a select box for widget types. But, it doesn't work correctly.

As you see, I trying to add WC_Widget_Products and WC_Widget_Top_Rated_Products widgets with different options. But I can't use WC_Widget_Products twice or more.

```
/**
* Column Content (min:2 - max:3 column)
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @return void 
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
register_widget( 'Hw_Column_Widget' );
});

class Hw_Column_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Sets up the widgets name etc
 */
public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'hw_column_widget',
        'description' => 'Prostore columns widget',
    );

    parent::__construct( 'hw_column_widget', __( 'Home Columns', 'theme' ), $widget_ops );
}

/**
 * Outputs the content of the widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    //the_widget($widget, $instance, $args);
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_one'] ) ) {
        $t1 = $instance['title_one'];
    }

    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_two'] ) ) {
        $t2 = $instance['title_two'];
    }

    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_three'] ) ) {
        $t3 = $instance['title_three'];
    }

    $column_first = $instance['column_first'];
    $column_second = $instance['column_second'];
    $column_third = $instance['column_third'];

    echo '<div class="woocommerce columns-3">';

        switch ($column_first) {
            case "recent":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t1.'' );
                break;
            case "featured":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t1.'&show=featured' );
                break;
            case "popular":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Top_Rated_Products', 'title='.$t1.'' ) ;
                break;
            case "onsale":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t1.'&show=onsale' );
                break;                  
            default:
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t1.'&orderby=sales' );
        }

        switch ($column_second) {
            case "recent":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t2.'' );
                break;
            case "featured":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t2.'&show=featured' );
                break;
            case "popular":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Top_Rated_Products', 'title='.$t2.'' ) ;
                break;
            case "onsale":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t2.'&show=onsale' );
                break;                  
            default:
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t2.'&orderby=sales' );
        }

        switch ($column_third) {
            case "recent":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t3.'' );
                break;
            case "featured":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t3.'&show=featured' );
                break;
            case "popular":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Top_Rated_Products', 'title='.$t3.'' ) ;
                break;
            case "onsale":
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t3.'&show=onsale' );
                break;                  
            default:
                the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Products', 'title='.$t3.'&orderby=sales' );
        }           

    echo '</div>';

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}


/**
 * Outputs the options form on admin
 *
 * @param array $instance The widget options
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title= __('Home Columns', 'prostore');

    if(isset($instance['title_one'])) { $title_one = esc_attr($instance['title_one']); }
    if(isset($instance['title_two'])) { $title_two = esc_attr($instance['title_two']); }        
    if(isset($instance['title_three'])) { $title_three = esc_attr($instance['title_three']); }

    if(isset($instance['column_first'])) { $column_first = esc_attr($instance['column_first']); }
    if(isset($instance['column_second'])) { $column_second = esc_attr($instance['column_second']); }
    if(isset($instance['column_third'])) { $column_third = esc_attr($instance['column_third']); }
    ?>
    <h3>1. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_one' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_one' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_one' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_one ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_first'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_first'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_first'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_first=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_first=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_first=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_first=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_first=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>
    <h3>2. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_two' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_two' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_two' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_two ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_second'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_second'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_second'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_second=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_second=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_second=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_second=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_second=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>        
    <h3>3. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_three' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_three' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_three' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_three ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_third'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_third'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_third'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_third=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_third=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_third=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_third=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_third=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>        
<?php
}


/**
 * Processing widget options on save
 *
 * @param array $new_instance The new options
 * @param array $old_instance The previous options
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    // processes widget options to be saved
    foreach( $new_instance as $key => $value )
    {
        $updated_instance[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
    }

    return $updated_instance;
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try using the same widget twice? Does the issue occur only with 'WC_Widget_Products' widget?

Comment: It always shows first select with first title. They are woocommerce widgets. WC_Widget_Products codes here [link](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-products.php)

Comment: Are you aware that you can pass your widget in as an object in the latest WordPress version rather than dealing with strings? Have you tried passing in an array rather than a string for the instance arguments?

Comment: I've written custom functions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written custom functions for queries.

```
<?php
/**
 * Column Content (min:2 - max:3 column)
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @return void 
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
register_widget( 'Hw_Column_Widget' );
});

class Hw_Column_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Sets up the widgets name etc
 */
public function __construct() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'hw_column_widget',
        'description' => 'Columns widget',
    );

    parent::__construct( 'hw_column_widget', __( 'Home Columns', 'theme' ), $widget_ops );
}

/**
 * Outputs the content of the widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    //the_widget($widget, $instance, $args);
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_one'] ) ) {
        $t1 = $instance['title_one'];
    }

    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_two'] ) ) {
        $t2 = $instance['title_two'];
    }

    if ( ! empty( $instance['title_three'] ) ) {
        $t3 = $instance['title_three'];
    }

    $column_first = $instance['column_first'];
    $column_second = $instance['column_second'];
    $column_third = $instance['column_third'];

    echo '<div class="woocommerce columns-3">';

        switch ($column_first) {
            case "recent":
                $this->recent($t1);
                break;
            case "featured":
                $this->featured($t1);
                break;
            case "popular":
                $this->popular($t1);
                break;
            case "onsale":
                $this->onsale($t1);
                break;                  
            case "best":
                $this->best($t1);
                break;
        }

        switch ($column_second) {
            case "recent":
                $this->recent($t2);
                break;
            case "featured":
                $this->featured($t2);
                break;
            case "popular":
                $this->popular($t2);
                break;
            case "onsale":
                $this->onsale($t2);
                break;                  
            case "best":
                $this->best($t2);
                break;
        }

        switch ($column_third) {
            case "recent":
                $this->recent($t3);
                break;
            case "featured":
                $this->featured($t3);
                break;
            case "popular":
                $this->popular($t3);
                break;
            case "onsale":
                $this->onsale($t3);
                break;                  
            case "best":
                $this->best($t3);
                break;
        }           

    echo '</div>';

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}


/**
 * Outputs the options form on admin
 *
 * @param array $instance The widget options
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title= __('Home Columns', 'prostore');

    if(isset($instance['title_one'])) { $title_one = esc_attr($instance['title_one']); }
    if(isset($instance['title_two'])) { $title_two = esc_attr($instance['title_two']); }        
    if(isset($instance['title_three'])) { $title_three = esc_attr($instance['title_three']); }

    if(isset($instance['column_first'])) { $column_first = esc_attr($instance['column_first']); }
    if(isset($instance['column_second'])) { $column_second = esc_attr($instance['column_second']); }
    if(isset($instance['column_third'])) { $column_third = esc_attr($instance['column_third']); }
    ?>
    <h3>1. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_one' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_one' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_one' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_one ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_first'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_first'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_first'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_first=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_first=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_first=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_first=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_first=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>
    <h3>2. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_two' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_two' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_two' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_two ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_second'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_second'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_second'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_second=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_second=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_second=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_second=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_second=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>        
    <h3>3. Kolon</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_three' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'prostore' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title_three' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title_three' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title_three ); ?>" />
    </p>        
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_third'); ?>">İçerik: 
            <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('column_third'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('column_third'); ?>">
                <option value='recent'<?php echo ($column_third=='recent')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Son Eklenen Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='featured'<?php echo ($column_third=='featured')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Öne Çıkan Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option>
                <option value='popular'<?php echo ($column_third=='popular')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Popüler Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='onsale'<?php echo ($column_third=='onsale')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('İndirimli Ürünler','prostore'); ?></option> 
                <option value='best'<?php echo ($column_third=='best')?'selected':''; ?>><?php _e('Çok Satanlar','prostore'); ?></option> 
            </select>                
        </label>
    </p>        
<?php
}


/**
 * Processing widget options on save
 *
 * @param array $new_instance The new options
 * @param array $old_instance The previous options
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    // processes widget options to be saved
    foreach( $new_instance as $key => $value )
    {
        $updated_instance[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
    }

    return $updated_instance;
}

/**
 * Recent Products
 *
 */ 
public function recent($title = '') {

    echo '<div class="widget woocommerce widget_products">';
    echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
    echo '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'product',
        'status'            =>  'publish',
        'no_found_rows'     =>  1,
        'posts_per_page'    =>  10,
        'orderby'           =>  'date',
        'order'             =>  'DESC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $product->get_title() ).'">';
    echo $product->get_image();
    echo '<span class="product-title">'.$product->get_title().'</span>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Featured Products
 *
 */     
public function featured($title = '') {

    echo '<div class="widget woocommerce widget_products">';
    echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
    echo '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';

    $meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'   => '_featured',
        'value' => 'yes'
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'product',
        'status'            =>  'publish',
        'no_found_rows'     =>  1,
        'posts_per_page'    =>  10,
        'orderby'           =>  'date',
        'order'             =>  'DESC',
        'meta_query'        =>  $meta_query
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $product->get_title() ).'">';
    echo $product->get_image();
    echo '<span class="product-title">'.$product->get_title().'</span>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Popular Products
 *
 */     
public function popular($title = '') {

    echo '<div class="widget woocommerce widget_products">';
    echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
    echo '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';

    add_filter( 'posts_clauses',  array( WC()->query, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'product',
        'status'            =>  'publish',
        'no_found_rows'     =>  1,
        'posts_per_page'    =>  10,
        'orderby'           =>  'date',
        'order'             =>  'DESC'
    );

    $args['meta_query'] = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $product->get_title() ).'">';
    echo $product->get_image();
    echo '<span class="product-title">'.$product->get_title().'</span>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( WC()->query, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );
    wp_reset_query(); 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}   

/**
 * On Sale Products
 *
 */     
public function onsale($title = '') {

    echo '<div class="widget woocommerce widget_products">';
    echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
    echo '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        'no_found_rows'     => 1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'meta_query'        => WC()->query->get_meta_query(),
        'post__in'          => array_merge( array( 0 ), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $product->get_title() ).'">';
    echo $product->get_image();
    echo '<span class="product-title">'.$product->get_title().'</span>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Best Selling Products
 *
 */     
public function best($title = '') {

    echo '<div class="widget woocommerce widget_products">';
    echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
    echo '<h2 class="widgettitle">'.$title.'</h2>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'product',
        'status'            =>  'publish',
        'no_found_rows'     =>  1,
        'posts_per_page'    =>  10,
        'orderby'           =>  'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'          =>  'total_sales',
        'order'             =>  'DESC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $product->get_title() ).'">';
    echo $product->get_image();
    echo '<span class="product-title">'.$product->get_title().'</span>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}   
}
```